# Facebook scraper ignores default language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, social-network

I have a Drupal 7 setup with an internationalized site. The default languages is English but the content is also available in German. However the site focuses on a German audience. As in Drupal you cannot switch the default languages without messing up all string translations, we have a custom language negotiation rule implemented (`hook_language_negotiation_info()`) that makes sure if no session or query parameter (like `lang=en`) is set, the site is shown in German. So, to make it short: If an user accesses our site like this:

http://www.example.com

it will be shown in German. Nevertheless Facebooks open graph scraper scraps the site always in English, as it would add programmatically `lang=en` to all URLs. How can that be? we have the following language specific meta tags:

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/node/581?lang=en" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" />
<link href="https://www.example.com/task/581" rel="alternate" hreflang="de" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
```

Does anybody know, what I could do, to convince Facebook open graph scraper to scrape the German version as default?

Comment: are you using metatag module?

Comment: @oksana-c Yes, metatag module is installed.

Comment: do your other tags (like description and so on) show up in German on the page where you copied your tags from?

Comment: @oksana-c Yes, the other tags show up in German.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly how the following tags are generated I cannot provide the exact solution to your issue, but only to point out what causes the Facebook to grab EN version.

```
1. <link href="https://www.example.com/node/581?lang=en" rel="alternate"
> hreflang="en" />

2. <link href="https://www.example.com/task/581"
> rel="alternate" hreflang="de" />
```

Tags 1 & 2 have `rel` attribute set to `alternative`, which tells facebook that both links from tag 1 & 2 can be used for fetching info. Therefore it grabs the first one in line.

Each page should have `rel="canonical"` tag that will tell facebook and all other crawlers, that it is a primary url for that page that should be used for fetching info.

I do not know if you have a link tag with `rel="canonical"` in your source code, as you only copied a portion of your meta tags. I suggest you check if it is present, and what page version it points to. If it is not present, add it.

Also, meta tag og:url should point to the right version of the page.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/task/581" />
```

Test your tags by fetching new meta info via [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).